# PostgreSQL No Mapping between account name and security IDs

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

I downloaded the installation file on https://www.postgresql.org/. I have Windows 10. As soon as I click on the installer of PostgreSQL, I face an issue:[image]

Do somebody know where to look for the solution? Thanks. I tried tens of ways, nothing helps. I tried to make some some changes in Windows log files, I changed user, I tried to open through the administrator rights and others ways.

Comment: I found this link, hopefully it will be useful: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-meant-by-no-mapping-between-account-names/dcccb1bb-1c4d-4bd5-91a7-832cabf9c86b

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL did you downloaded? From the [Windows installers page](https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) the last version tested with Windows 10 is PostgreSQL 10. Version 11, 12 and 13 seems to have been tested only on [Windows servers editions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server)

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKpMn.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHvMc.png)

It gives this error when characters that do not match ing are used in the user name. I found the problem by trying for 4 hours. windows system system information rename this computer and determine the user name in accordance with the English alphabet

Answer (score -1):

Did you changed your wib user name
I solved this problem by changing my user name to original one

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).